# How do I use the 32-bit version of Internet Explorer 11 on a 64-bit OS?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I need to run the 32 bit version of Windows Internet Explorer 11 for a specific app. But my OS is 64 bit. How do I specifically do this? Is it even possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Your OS, being a 64-bit system, is able to install and execute both 32-bit and 64-bit applications.

**By default, Internet Explorer is executed using its 32-bit version**.

Usually, the paths of Internet Explorer are:

- 32-bit: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe`
- 64-bit: `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe`

Answer (score 3):

IE 11 is 64 bit framework, on Windows 7 64 bit if you dont enable Enhanced Protection Mode in Advanced Settings>Security it will always run in 32 bit mode

Comment: @DavidPostill: doesn't work for me.  Unless that setting is changed, choosing "Internet Explorer (64-bit)" launches 32-bit IE.  (Actually both a 64-bit process and a 32-bit process are running, but it seems to be the 32-bit one that I'm actually interacting with.  For example, without turning on that option, I couldn't use the 64-bit Java plugin.)

Comment: ... and if I *do* turn on that setting, I get the 64-bit IE even if I launch the 32-bit one.

Answer (score 2):

Win 7 uses the 32-bit version of IE by default. However, if you want to be absolutely sure, just create a shortcut and add C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe as the program to call.

Answer (score 2):

If you've executed "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" and still don't see 32-bit iexplore process in task manager, check your IE plugins.
In my case there was iMacros 64-bit plugin installed.
Somehow it prevented IE32 from running end started IE64 instead.
After uninstalling the 64-bit plugin I was able to start IE32.